# Wait for an Async method to finish from a separate method

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous, postsharp

Using `PostSharp` to wrap a WCF Service call with AOP Logging with the `OnEntry` and `OnExit` methods for `OnMethodBoundaryAspect`.

> **Process:**
> `OnEntry()` is called, a `DateTime` signaling the start of the call is stored in a property and an Asynchronous Task is started before the method ends while that Task continues on.
>
> This Task formats some information on service call for logging and can take some time. These values are stored as properties in this class for logging.
>
> `OnExit()` is called, another `DateTime` signaling the end of the call is stored. At this point I need to make sure the Task started in the `OnEntry()` method is complete and all the properties are ready to be logged to the database.

The question is how can I make sure the Task started in `OnEntry()` is complete for use in `OnExit()`? I have considered setting up a boolean, `while(false) {Thread.Sleep(100);}` then finish off when true, but that doesn't feel right for some reason.

Below is the code I currently have set up for this.

```
class LogMethodCallAttribute : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    Int32 userId;
    String methodCall;
    String ip;
    DateTime entryTime;
    DateTime exitTime;

    /// Performs tasks on a Method before its execution.
    public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        // Set OnEntry Time
        entryTime = DateTime.Now;
        
        if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AOPLoggingEnabled"] == "1")
        {
            MessageProperties prop = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties;
            // Queue the logging to run on the ThreadPool so the service can finish the request.
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SetUpLog(args, prop));            
        }
    }
    
    public override void OnExit(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        // Set OnExit Time
        exitTime = DateTime.Now;
        
        // Need to make sure the Task running SetUpLog is complete and all props set.

        // Log the details of this method call.
        Logs.LogWebServiceCall(userId, methodName, ip, entryTime, exitTime);
    }
    
    // Format details for logging.
    private void SetUpLog(MethodExecutionArgs args, MessageProperties prop)
    {
        // Retrieve all the required data and do any formatting.
        userId = ...;
        methodCall = ...;
        ip = ...;
    }
}
```

Comment: Store the task returned from `Task.Factory.StartNew` in a vriable and `Wait` for it in OnExit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Okay, I think I misunderstood you.

Basically, you need to remember the `Task` that you've started, and then you can just call `Wait()` to wait until it's finished:

```
class LogMethodCallAttribute : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    Task task;
    ... as before ...

    public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        ...
        task = Task.Factory.StartNew(...);
    }

    public override void OnExit(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        exitTime = DateTime.Now;
        // Wait for the task to have completed...
        task.Wait();
        // Now you can use the fields
    }
}
```

Personally I would actually *not* just set the fields in the task though - I'd make the task a `Task<T>` for some `T` which contains the logging parameters. Then you can make the *only* field in your attribute the task, and have:

```
var loggingParameters = task.Result;
... use the logging parameters
```

Comment: The service calls themselves can take some time. Originally we didn't care about start/end times and simply fired off the logging asynchronously and forgot about it. With this new requirement, the service call will take longer 99.99% of the time, and all the data should be waiting in the fields ready to go. If I am understanding correctly, you are saying that the way it should be is the method creating the Task completes before the Task itself, which is kind of the opposite of what I am trying to do?

Comment: @WebDevNewbie: I suspect I've misunderstood your requirements. Will edit my post.

Comment: Thank you very much, that extra suggestion about using Task<T> really helped out as well :)